# How force css to works on Edge/IE the same as on Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in inline function to show a monthly calendar. Working on custom css I edited its appearence and works as expected on Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari) but on Edge its behavior is strange.

This is how it works on Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari:
[image]

This is how it works on Edge:
[image]

As you can see dots' position start on wrong position, only when I move mouse over it the dots' position go where is suppose to be.

This is part of .css:

```
#calendarMonth .day::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(238,238,238, 0.5);
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* android, safari, chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* old firefox */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* old opera */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* old IE */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*standard */
}
#calendarMonth .day:hover::before{
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.8s ease;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

I'm using `top`, `left` and `transform: translate()` to set correct position. Why Edge doens't work like other browsers?

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Microsoft is abandoning their proprietary Edge rendering engine, and moving to Chromium.  So give it a couple months and Edge should render exactly the same as Chrome.

Comment: What a good news! Ok so I won't spend more time on fixing it for Edge. Will IE use Chromium as well? Because IE too has a little problem, is not like Edge, but all dots are more up than what they should be!

Comment: IE won’t be updated, but I suggest checking your stats to see how many IE users are actually accessing your site